# How do I become a "superuser"?

Tags: command-line, sudo, dpkg

The following command fails with an error:

```
$ dpkg -i libmotif*i386.deb
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

How do I become a superuser? I thought I was the superuser?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207466/how-to-run-applications-as-root) should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

In all Unix systems, including Linux a [**Superuser**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) is the system user who has all permissions to be able to perform administrative tasks. This can be the user `root` but this user is diabled in Ubuntu for security reasons.

The Ubuntu way to perform admistrative tasks is to temporarily gain superuser privileges by putting the command `sudo` (`s`uper `u`ser `do`) in front of another command that requires superuser powers:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

Then you will be asked for your password (which is identical to your login password):

```
[sudo] password for lasse:
```

Note that you don't see anything in terminal while typing this passoword (not even asterixes).

Users that are allowed to be administrators on creation of their account are put on a list of `sudoers` to enable the system to look them up before granting administrative privileges with `sudo`.

For further reading and alternative ways on how to become superuser or root see:

- [What are the differences between sudo, su, visudo, chroot, and gksu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197772/what-are-the-differences-between-sudo-su-visudo-chroot-and-gksu)
- [What are the differences between "su", "sudo -s", "sudo -i", "sudo su"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i)
- [Why is it bad to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root)

Please also note that you can seriously harm your system when running a bad command as superuser. Sometimes you will not even be able to repair it. Therefore be careful what you do as superuser, and **think twice** before you press enter.

Comment: To run graphical applications (e.g. Gedit), use gksudo rather than sudo - see the explanation in the Ubuntu documentation for the reason - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo

Answer (score 2):

Prefix `sudo` to your command to be a `superuser`. Hence, run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i libmotif*i386.deb
```

Running this command would prompt you for your password. Type the password for your user account and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You won't see the characters as you type your password (not even asterisks *).

For more information on `sudo`, [read this wonderful ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

Answer (score 0):

Just do this If you are on Ubuntu

```
naren@kadmin-KCPL190: sudo su
```

Then you will now be a root user and can do anything

```
root@kadmin-KCPL190:# dpkg -i libmotif*i386.deb
```

will work

Be careful. If you set a password for root user then it asks you the same for landing to root.Else it will just make you superuser.