# Why can't I create a file in “/” or main Directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to create a file in "/" directory (which contains bin, boot , cdrom, dev, etc) but I am unable to do so. Although I am the one who install ubuntu and I am the root user? The error I get is of permission denied.
When I used sudo it asks for password but I haven't set any password for it.

Also I cannot calculate the hash of a file in this directory.

I am sorry for my lame question as I just have switched to linux after using windows for long time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. In all likelihood your user does not have permissions to write in that folder. Could you please post the output of the command `ls -la /` ?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu most anything you do outside of your own home directory requires you to become a superuser, in other words to become Root, or to gain root privileges which are all the same.

- [How do I become a "superuser"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233378/how-do-i-become-a-superuser)

Now with being root you will have a greater responsibility to keep your system in a stable state but also a very high risk to break it. Root can do anything including breaking your OS to a state where you will have to re-install Ubuntu as the only option remaining for repair.

There are only rare conditions where creating directories outside of `/home/` may be needed. It certainly is not the way our understanding of the file system heirarchy is. In addition backups or a system reinstallation becomes harder with every single file residing outside of `/home`.

> So if you are a beginner to the Ubuntu world I strongly advise you to **not create directories or files outside of your home** directory unless you really really know that you badly need them to be there, and your are 100% certain that there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is file permissions, you can start a root shell with

```
 sudo bash
```

But be careful what you do. Also please note that, on Linux, you usally don't create dictionaries in the roor dir / - if you want to store files such as documents or photos, they should go in your home directory.

```
echo $HOME
```

will print the path of the current user's home directory to the shell.