# `sudo userx` returns `sudo: userx: command not found` , why?

Tags: sudo

just installed this Linux disto ver 13.04 installed Xfce 4.0x got it running just fine then for some reason that good'O sudo stopped working all by itself why? I now type in sudo and this is what I get

```
Wed Oct  2 15:23:06 CDT 2013
[15:23 userx@bw ~] > sudo
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user
            name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
            groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid]
            [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
            groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
```

so I then type in this

```
[15:23 userx@bw ~] > sudo userx
[sudo] password for userx: 
sudo: userx: command not found
[15:23 userx@bw ~] >
```

and that is what I get after I type in my password

what is going on here? how am I to install anything? wish they'd never messed with su installed the root user account by default then let you create users

Comment: This is the standard behavior for sudo. You need to type a command after sudo. userx command is not found because your username is not a command.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` hasn't broke. You don't know how to use it. sudo is an anagram of **S**uper **U**ser **DO**. And you are telling the super user to run `userx` and he tells you back that the command `userx` does not exist.

```
$ userx
No command 'userx' found, did you mean:
 Command 'users' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'userv' from package 'userv' (universe)
userx: command not found
```

For actually using `sudo` you have to know what you will run:

```
sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for braiam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

I bet that if you run a command that actually exist it will run ok. BTW, **`sudo` is not `su`**. While `su` changes your user to root, in Ubuntu root is disabled in favor of 1 time/for 1 use superuser privileges `sudo`.

To update, remove and manage packages I would suggest you to use the GUI.

Good to read about `su` and `sudo`:

- [Is there a difference between sudo su - root and sudo -u root -H /bin/bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34670/41104)
- [Difference between “su”, “sudo -s”, “sudo -i”](https://askubuntu.com/q/70534/169736)
- [What's the difference between the commands “su -s” and “sudo -s”?](https://superuser.com/q/29/235569)
- [How to run applications as root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/207466/169736)