# How do I run any application as root?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root, ubuntu-minimal

While logged in as the root account of a CLI installation, almost every application gives me this error:

```
Don't run this as root!
```

I want to bypass this error and run the application while logged into root. How do I do this?

Edit: I understand the risks of using the root user and I will still want to use it. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need to run applications as root?

Comment: @Pilot6 The root account will be my main account on the system.

Comment: Why the downvote? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ant what is the reason of having root as the main account? It is a bad idea. I did not downvote.

Comment: @Pilot6 I know it is. But that is not the question.

Comment: There is serious security implications of having root account enabled.  Avoid it as much as possible

Comment: Read this: http://askubuntu.com/a/207481/163331

Comment: Unless you know it's a bad idea but you still want to do it...

Comment: Then these will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root and  http://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root and http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login and http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root

Comment: I do understand the risks of using the root user @Parto , and already have it enabled.

Comment: "Edit: I understand the risks of using the root user." No, you don't.  Use a system that uses root and not sudo by default. Picking Ubuntu implies using sudo.

Comment: You have no right to tell me what I do and don't know. I know the risks of using the root user, and I'm not using it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You may add your very own User with sudo rights. 
You can create a User and add this User to the **sudo** Group.

```
sudo adduser youruser sudo
```

Or if you already have a user, you can add this to the **sudo** Group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo youruser
```

After this log in to this user with `su youruser` and try to run the installation again with `sudo yourinstallcommand`.

You should never run any Installations with the `root` User. User always your very own User with **sudo** due to security reasons.

Comment: I re-worded my question so people may understand I am looking to run the application using the root account. Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I do not wish to use this method.

Comment: You cant install the software with the root user. Just add your very own User with root privileges as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password) has an answer that works. Using the root account is insecure and I understand that. The accepted answer [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password) is going to help me a lot. Thank you for your suggestions, criticism, and help, [bobbyblackblech](https://askubuntu.com/users/486940/bobbybackblech), [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6), [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg), and [Parto](https://askubuntu.com/users/163331/parto).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with `sudo` by default. `sudo` is a package/command that allows you to run any command/application as root (`sudo` stands for *SuperUser Do*).

Your user is by default in `sudoers` file if you are administrator (who installs the system, per example).

Simply type:

```
sudo <command>
```

Example:

```
sudo gedit
```

This runs gedit as root. **BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL WITH SUDO AND SUPERUSER/ROOT**.

Comment: I understand what sudo is. I have already found a solution.

Comment: Then you must mark the question as answered.

Comment: I cannot mark it for 2 days, @Juanjo

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sudo, you might also need to disable X access control within your user X session:

```
xhost +
sudo foo
...
sudo bar
```

For foo and bar being X applications.

But I agree with everybody: don't do that!